# Fastest way to stop and start cassandra nodes before updates

Tags: cassandra

What would be the best way how to stop Cassandra nodes before application updates and database updates, and to afterwards start them? Currently I'm going through each node VM and stopping them using the command `sudo service cassandra stop` and then after the update is done, I'm doing the same, just starting them with command `sudo service cassandra start`. With few nodes it's OK, but I have 20 nodes on a server, and it takes some time to do that.

Is there any better/more efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to do this - use `for` loop in shell + `ssh`, use [pssh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pssh), etc.  You just need to remember that it's better to perform rolling restart of the individual Cassandra nodes, so you need to have to wait until Cassandra starts again. Something like:

```
for host in `cat your-host-list.txt`; do
   ssh user@${host} 'sudo service cassandra stop && your_update_command && sudo service cassandra start
done
```

or slightly easier with `pssh`:

```
pssh -l user -h your-host-list.txt -p 1 -t 0 'sudo service cassandra stop && your_update_command && sudo service cassandra start
```

- `-p 1` tells to execute only one command in parallel
- `t 0` instructs to wait for execution without timeout